# I Cant Open Flutter URL Via URL Launcher

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

My Launcher is not working ! launch (overwitted).. What's the problem here?

[image]

Comment: You can refer [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/launching-urls-flutter-url_launcher/) for a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying out the URL launcher in Android and the device API is 30+, try adding the query intent outside of the application tag in the Android Manifest.

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Note: Use a stable Gradle version greater than 4 and update the studio to the latest version.

You can refer to:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you use is old. You also need to parse the url.

```
final url = Uri.parse('https://google.com');
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: Ok... But Still Link Not Working ... What's Going On .. https://ibb.co/1qhFtFQ

Comment: Is the internet enabled on the device? It works for me.

Comment: Wrap with try catch so that you can catch error with app crash and identify error easily